# How to autoplay audiomack iframe

Tags: audio, iframe, autoplay

With soundcloud you can add the parameter auto_play=true in the iframe src attribute to autoplay the audio file.

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F494237829&show_artwork=true&auto_play=true
```

I'd like to do the same with an audiomack iframe.  I have so far created the following iframe (see below)  but have had no luck finding anything that works to allow this to autoplay.  Is it possible?  After hours of searching I can't seem to find anything helpful regarding this.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://audiomack.com/embed/album/shy-glizzy/fully-loaded"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Audiomack support directly I received a reply stating that this is not supported and they do not plan to add support for this.

Answer (score 0):

Audiomack engineer here. We actually do have an `autoplay` parameter so your embed code should look something like:

`<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://audiomack.com/embed/album/shy-glizzy/fully-loaded?autoplay=1"></iframe>`

That being said, nowadays browsers tend to block media with autoplay because media playback needs to be the result of a user interaction. Sometimes they may allow autoplay if the media is muted (in the case of video) but obviously that doesn't help much here in the case of audio. Both SoundCloud and Audiomack embeds will attempt to play if possible but testing in Chrome, FF, and Safari right now yield similar results.